# Is there a possiblity to create a variable with a string for everything inside of a table?

Tags: lua, computercraft

Just wondering about that, because i don't find a solution for it. Pretty sure because I'm new to this c: Thanks for your help.

Edit: for explanation im gonna explain it with the code a bit.

```
local FileList = fs.list("") --Makes a Table with all the files and directories available (as strings) on the PC it's running on (Inside of a mod called computercraft for minecraft)

for _, file in ipairs(FileList) do 
    --Here I need a function which assigns every string from the table to a variable, just for the explanation I'll call it unknown.function
   
    unknown.function
end 

while true do
    print(a) --a is for example one of the different variables made from the "unknown.function" 
    sleep(1)
end
```

Comment: Give a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @lhf I have a table which can have more or less in it. It depends on what machine it runs. After it I would like to have variables which contains the string of every object of the table, to use it later in the code.

Comment: [`table.concat`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.concat). If that's not what you need, we'll need further details about what you're looking for.

Comment: Mhm. I'm trying to explain it to you with the part of my code. Just a sec im gonna edit my question then.

Comment: To be clear, you want for example `FileList[1]` to be accessible by a variable called `myFile` which is the string it holds? i dont understand how this is useful, given the context of the code in your question, the print would look like `print(myFile)` to print `"myFile"`. or are you looking for the string to be the complete path and the variable is just the file name?

Comment: You could store your "variables" in a table as string keys, but if your data is already in string form, then like @Nifim, I don't see how that would be useful.

Comment: The Answer from juniorGY is what I've needed to know, anyways thanks for all of your help too c:

Comment: Ok, if that's the case why not just use `FileList`? The 2 tables(`FileList` and `AllFiles`) are identical, though i guess if `FileList` contained some string keys those are omitted by using `ipairs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE this?

```
AllFiles = {}

function Crazyfunction(file)

 AllFiles[table.getn(AllFiles)+1] = file
 
end

local FileList = fs.list("")

for _, file in ipairs(FileList) do 
    Crazyfunction(file)
end 

while true do
    print(AllFiles[NUMBE_OF_FILE_HERE])
    sleep(1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
local FileList = fs.list("")

for _, file in ipairs(FileList) do 
    -- file is the variable which contains a string from the table.
    print(file)
    sleep(1)
end
```

What you want is... already what your loop does. You just added an extra loop for no reason.